# Snow Leopard, Homebrew: X11 Not Installed (But xQuartz is)

Tags: x11, homebrew

I'm trying to install some formulas using homebrew but `brew doctor` tells me that I don't have X11 installed. Since it can't find X11, it's not able to build a bunch of formulas that I need installed. I did download xQuartz and installed it but it seems that homebrew ignores those packages. Is there a way to set homebrew to use xQuartz and not the built-in (non-installed) X11? I was under the impression that xQuartz is X11.

I'm currently downloading XCode 3.2.6 to see if this will solve my problem but it's going to take 5 hours to do so.

Comment: So I found a (temp) workaround to my problem after googling around.
As found on this page: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9264

I ended up moving the X11 folder out of /usr and symlinked /opt/X11 to /usr instead. (I believe these folders are from an XQuartz installation)

(`$ mv /usr/X11 /`
`$ ln -s /opt/X11 /usr`)

Homebrew will warn your that XQuartz isn't known to be fully compatible with Homebrew and suggests using Apple's X11 instead... Which I guess answers my question about whether the two are the same thing.

This is still a clunky solution but it will do for now...

Answer (score 0):

XQuartz detection is fixed in newer versions of Homebrew. Do `brew update` and the problem should go away.